# Loading multiple images with Picasso on background

Tags: android, caching, imageview, lazy-loading, picasso

I am trying to get loaded an array of 20 urls in background with Picasso. So far i have the next code:

```
Log.d("GAME", "Loading all images");
for (int i = gamePieces.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   GamePiece p = gamePieces[i];
   Log.d("GAME", "I will load " + p.getImage());
   Picasso.with(context).load(p.getImage()).into(target);
}
//loading the first one
Picasso.with(context).load(piece.getImage()).into(target);
```

And my `target` object is the next one:

```
Target target = new Target() {
       @Override
       public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
           Log.d("GAME", "Image loaded" + ++test);
           gameImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //ImageView to show the images
       }

       @Override
       public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {}

       @Override
       public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {}
   };
```

I want to pre load the images so i can show one by one in the ImageView any time the user clicks a button.

The first image is loading so fast(that's cool) but the other images at the for loop never get load. How can i fix this? i need the images to start loading in the for loop.

Comment: 1.) ALWAYS keep a strong reference to Picasso Targets somewhere because Picasso itself will only keep a WeakReference - and the Target will be garbage collected before the image loading is done. 2.) I am not entirely sure, but from the source code it seems that Picasso will only handle one request for each instance of Target or ImageView that you pass into an `into()` - maybe have a look yourself to (dis-)confirm.

Comment: @david.mihola How can i keep a strong reference to Picasso targets? What do you mean by "maybe have a look yourself to (dis-)confirm" is that a method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to use:
 `Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(p.getImage()).fetch();`

Here is the reference: https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html

Comment: Reference Link is Dead.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try doing the following:

```
Picasso mPicasso = Picasso.with(context); //Single instance

//if you are indeed loading the first one this should be in top, before the iteration.
Picasso.with(context).load(piece.getImage()).into(target);

Log.d("GAME", "Loading all images");
for (int i = gamePieces.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

   GamePiece p = gamePieces[i];
   Log.d("GAME", "I will load " + p.getImage());
   mPicasso.load(p.getImage()).into(target); 

}
```

You can alway refer to the examples [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/PicassoSampleActivity.java)